# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields' (odoo)

Tags: model-view-controller, odoo, erp, odoo-9

I am using Odoo v9 to create a website, when someone navigates to one of the pages in my website (/order/time), he gets the error detailed below.

Model:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
  class odss_sale_order(models.Model):
      _name = "_order"
      order_date = fields.Text(required=True)
```

The Important Part of the View:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div t-field="odss_order.order_date"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 243, in
>   _handle_exception
>       response = super(ir_http, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 157, in
>   _handle_exception
>       return request._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 784, in _handle_exception
>       return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 182, in
>   _dispatch
>       result = request.dispatch()   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 843, in dispatch
>       r = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 315, in checked_call
>       result.flatten()   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1444, in flatten
>       self.response.append(self.render())   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1437, in render
>       context=request.context)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
>       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 166, in render
>       return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
>       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in render
>       return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
>       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1074, in render
>       return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py",
>   line 250, in wrapper
>       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 254, in render
>       return self.render_node(element, qwebcontext, generated_attributes=qwebcontext.pop('generated_attributes', ''))
>   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in
>   render_node
>       result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 448, in
>   render_tag_call
>       d[0] = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, d)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in
>   render_node
>       result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 325, in
>   render_element
>       raise_qweb_exception(message="Could not render element %r" % element.tag, node=element, template=template)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in
>   render_element
>       generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))   File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in
>   render_node
>       result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)   File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 503, in
>   render_tag_field
>       field = record._fields[field_name] QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'

QWeb:

```
Could not render element 'div' The error occured while rendering the template 900

<div class="input-group">
                                                        <div t-field="odss_sale_order.order_date"/></div>
```

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Hamza Tahboub

Comment: is it a custom report?...did you override `get_html`?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried by addding this line in your top of the PY file.

`from openerp import models, fields, api, _`

Hope this will resolve it.

Thanks,
Chandni.